# Show landscape keyboard in a portrait only app

Tags: ios, keyboard, orientation

Is there a way to change the rotation of the keyboard? I have a method that monitors the orientation of the device and I was wondering if there was something I could add to there to change the keyboard when the app is in landscape. My app, however, is only set to portrait mode.

This is how I am getting the frame for the keyboard, but when I try to change the frame it doesn't accept my changes.

```
- (void)myNotificationMethod:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: No, I haven't @iOS_Binod

Comment: Please tell me if you get any solution. Thanks